# Accessing specific part of object

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an object I am trying to access and this is the `var_dump()`

```
object(GDS\Entity)#16 (5)
{
    ["str_kind":"GDS\Entity":private]=>
        string(13) "User Sessions" ["str_key_id":"GDS\Entity":private]=>
            string(16) "5649391675244544" ["str_key_name":"GDS\Entity":private]=>
                NULL ["mix_ancestry":"GDS\Entity":private]=>
                    NULL ["arr_data":"GDS\Entity":private]=>
                        array(1) {
                            ["session_id"]=> string(3) "123"
                        }
}
```

I know if I wanted to get the `session_id` and this object was stored in `$object` I would just do `$object->session_id`

But I am trying to get the `str_key_id (5649391675244544)` but I can't figure out how to access it.

Could anyone help me figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as

`$object->getKeyId();`

(Think you've already picked this up on GitHub ;)

Tom